# How to update related model fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models (purchase and stock), I Want when i purchase an item the quantity field in stock to be updated. (eg. i have 2 Mangoes in stock and i purchase 3 Mongoes, i want the updated stock to be 5 Mangoes)

My Models

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    stock_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)
    buying_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Stock, null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)
    buying_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)
```

Can anyone help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Django Signals.

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

```
def update_stock(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    product = instance.product.id    
    stock = Stock.objects.get(product=product.id)
    stock.quantity = stock.quantity + instance.quantity

post_save.connect(update_stock, sender=Purchase)
```

You can add the exceptions according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Django models like any variable

```
 CurrentPurchase.stock.quantity = 5
```

or you can use filter to get the object you want :

```
Model.objects.filter(AnotherModel=Model_)
```

Comment: Post the code first, you just posted the classes design 
Show me when someone buys a product what do you do in the code!

Comment: [This is the all what you need to know about django models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/)